# How to configure tox to access environment variables?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fastapi, tox

I am using tox to run pytest. Pytest runs test cases that tests  API endpoints that required crednetials. I do not want to save my credentials in the code and set is as an environment variable in azure pipelines which will then call tox to run tests. Kindly suggest how I can make tox access environment variables or if there are better ways to handle credentials when testing APIs.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify which environment variables are exported to tox and its subprocesses using the [`passenv` option](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#conf-passenv) in the Tox configuration.